# is there anything else to fix ext4 14.04 encrypted root? should I stay with ext4 or is another more likely to last longer?

Tags: filesystem

I can't get 14.04 to boot but from a 15.10 partition I can:

```
~$ sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/mapper/vgcrypt-lvroot 
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/mapper/vgcrypt-lvroot contains a file system with errors, checkforced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Error reading block 109051936 (Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? no
Error while scanning inodes (27000833): Can't read next inode
e2fsck: aborted
```

---

```
~$ sudo cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda8
LUKS header information for /dev/sda8

Version:        1
  Cipher name:      aes
  Cipher mode:      xts-plain64
  Hash spec:        sha1
  Payload offset:   4096
  MK bits:          512
MK digest:      66 13 1d f8 94 bf 70 a4 aa 37 ad 88 d8 ab fd b2 5f 5a 09 77 
MK salt:        43 66 df b3 d5 7a 6d bb b8 29 e6 b5 40 65 ca 9e 
            ee ae 20 63 f1 ad 93 ab d7 08 57 8c 59 68 20 1b 
MK iterations:  39125
UUID:           774e46b0-8c8f-49b9-aea9-b5e7ae1a2006

Key Slot 0: ENABLED
Iterations:             154031
Salt:                   d9 f5 4d f1 62 c7 85 b1 00 4b fd 83 b3 b4 91 aa 
                        d4 c7 1c dc 1d 5e 26 31 a2 28 71 45 86 61 18 97 
Key material offset:    8
AF stripes:             4000
Key Slot 1: DISABLED
Key Slot 2: DISABLED
```

Is there anything else I can do to fix my 14.04 or do I have to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

No, the best thing to do 1st is to boot from a live dvd, make sure to un-mount all disks and run:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda8
```

When asked to `Force rewrite <y>?` type `y` or `yes`.

(I assume sda8 by the way as it is in your 2nd message, change to what you need if not sda8; you can add a `-y` to the command so you do not need to confirm all the questions)

If this does not show any other errors re-do the

```
sudo fsck.ext4 -v /dev/mapper/vgcrypt-lvroot
```

as you did. If the 1st commands report any errors or irregulatiries  please add it into the question.

Extra comments:

- check the health of the disk. Maybe it is nothing but errors like this make me always suspicious of a failing hard disk.